# What is the minimum expected from a math PhD

Tags: phd, thesis, mathematics

I had a hard time deciding whether this question is more suitable for here or mathoverflow. I'm posting here if you think it is better to be on mathoverflow please let me know.

I'm a PhD student in mathematics getting close to end of my program and I have to wrap up my PhD thesis. My PhD has been pretty much a failure. Some of that can be attributed to my own personal characteristics and some for lacking a proper PhD advisor (I do have an official PhD advisor but never received any advising and was on my own for most of the time). What I decided to do during my PhD was to choose a group of well known conjectures in my specific sub-field and try to solve them. As you can already guess I didn't end up solving them and spent my PhD time on them (Partially because I couldn't give up and partially because my advisor didn't have problems for me). Now I have few months left. So far I have no publications (excluding the undergraduate era).

If I start writing my thesis right now what I could write up are a bunch of hypothetical methods that could end up solving one of those conjectures. But along the solutions I have made even more conjectures. I can  give some evidence that why these new conjectures are probably true and if true why they imply the well-known conjecture. Do you think something like this is acceptable as a PhD thesis in math? (The bottom line is that I haven't solved the problem, haven't solved a known problem with a different method or built any theory)

Well of course I should ask my advisor's opinion at the end, but before that I just wanted to know your opinions on this. (My advisor as of right now is pretty much unaware of what I've done so far)

Comment: Generally in a PhD you want to have proven at least something.....

Comment: I think you should definitely ask your advisor as soon as possible. Most likely, they alone decide or at least heavily influence the outcome. People here probably have different standards than the advisor. There are people obtaining a PhD just for political reasons without (much) to show. There maybe is a theoretical minimum for a phd (having addes human knowledge), in practise this is often not the case.

Comment: I would say, much depends also on the quality of the conjectures. If the mathematical structures permit, you may want to run computer experiments to get evidence that they do not fail outright with simple counterexamples.

Comment: The conjectures are well known, so presumably there are no simple counterexamples (though it never hurts to double check).

Comment: The answer to this question is defined by your committee and your university.  There is no general answer.  Having us make guesses based on your description of what you've done is almost totally useless.

Comment: I would say it depends on how independently interesting your new conjectures are, and if you can prove the small special cases of them.